# What's the best way to include e-mails as evidence from a technical perspective?

Tags: evidence, small-claims-court, email

It probably would be easiest to copy and paste quotes from emails into my evidence submission. But of course text could easily be changed in this format. I could take a screen shot of the email as I received it, and include the screen shot as evidence. The problem with this is highlighting certain lines of text would be harder.

The tribunal I am going through requests documents be submitted electronically.

At one point a person who tried to help mediate entered the conversation by e-mail. Out of privacy to him, can I redact his name or email address? The point would be the defendant did agree to something, but he sent it to the mediator and told him to forward it to me. (this wasn't a professional mediator, more like a mutual friend).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Submit emails in their totality**

Your testimonial affidavit can quote or cite them as applicable. There is no protection of anyone’s privacy in court.

By the way, the email where admissions were made is probably inadmissible if it was sent were in the course of *bona fide* negotiation to resolve the dispute. If the other party objects they will be thrown out - I wouldn’t hang my case on them.

Comment: Regarding last paragraph. Perhaps "admissions" might be inadmissible, but the actual agreement made during the negotiation is still admissible, correct?

Comment: @dutyanalysing unlikely - it’s a privileged document assuming it is more than a statement of undisputed facts or an assertion of rights.

Comment: I don't get it. If someone agrees to something and doesn't do it, why wouldn't that be breach of contract? This had nothing to do with admitting to anything.

Comment: @dutyanalysing not all agreements are contracts